# PHP: why dont you need a $ in front of a php variable?

Tags: php, pdo

New to php. I am writing a class and was wondering why some variable `$variable` does not need a `$` when calling `$this->variable`?

Comment: There is a `$` in the beginning of that variable reference already. It's not part of the variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Object Oriented Programming when you declare variables like so

```
public $variable;
```

these are no more variables but are the properties of the object of the class.
So when we call these properties we reference these through `$this->property`  Which means that we are calling the property of the present object. `$this` refers to the instance  of the present class. Whenever you would call properties and methods within class you have to use `$this->property-or-method`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the variable. It means object oriented. 
It's a reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in object oriented code.

- Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
- Primer:http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html

Example:

```
<?php
class Person {
    public $name;

    function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
};

$jack = new Person('Jack');
echo $jack->name;
```

This stores the 'Jack' string as a property of the object created.

Answer (score 2):

Because that variable is inside a larger variable called an `Object` and the object knows how to access it's inner variables / functions. Like a smart-variable.

Objects can be used to group data or similar functions (called method's when they are inside of an object)

For data/values, you could also use an array. It's common to see data stored in objects as well.

But you wouldn't store functions in an array. In PHP that's a no-go, but in JavaScript that's all good.

Back to objects, functions stored in objects are called methods. Objects can contain methods or properties.

Object Method / Function Example from: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

```
<?php
class foo
{
    function do_foo()
    {
        echo "Doing foo."; 
    }
}

$bar = new foo;
$bar->do_foo();
// also valid $bar::do_foo();
?>
```

Object Property / Variable Example From: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
   // valid as of PHP 5.6.0:
   public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
   // valid as of PHP 5.3.0:
   public $var2 = <<<EOD
hello world
EOD;
   // valid as of PHP 5.6.0:
   public $var3 = 1+2;
   // invalid property declarations:
   public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
   public $var5 = $myVar;

   // valid property declarations:
   public $var6 = myConstant;
   public $var7 = array(true, false);

   // valid as of PHP 5.3.0:
   public $var8 = <<<'EOD'
hello world
EOD;
}
?>
```